# Sencha Touch 2 global variable undefined

Tags: url, proxy, sencha-touch-2, global-variables

I am learning Sencha Touch 2 and I need a global variable. I used the following code to set a global variable called TID in my app.js file:

```
....
    launch: function() {
        // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
        Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

        // Initialize the main view
        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('Layouts.view.Main'));
        TID = 7;
    },
....
```

In a LIST view, I am successfully confirming the default set value and resetting the value with the following code:

```
....
itemtap: function(data, index){
    var record = data.getStore().getAt(index);

    var store = Ext.getStore('Sections');

    this.fireEvent('ListContent', store.getData().all[index].data.tid);
    this.TID = store.getData().all[index].data.tid;
    console.log('Confirming TID: ' + this.TID);
    console.log('Confirming TID: ' + TID);
},
....
```

The console.log code returns the following output:

```
Confirming TID: 10
Confirming TID: 7
```

I'm trying to use this TID value in a Store to filter content from a remote server with the following code:

```
....
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'http://myserver/sections/content/'+this.TID,

    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'JSON',
    }
},
....
```

And that is where the problem is. **this.TID** or **TID** both return **undefined** when inspected in the network traffic of my browser.

Answer (score 0):

The `url` parameter is set when the class itself is created -- not when the `Store` is instantiated. So when that file is first read, `TID` hasn't been set yet and won't be read again by the `Section` config. What you'll likely have to do with the setup you have is to use

```
var store = Ext.getStore('Sections');
store.getProxy().setUrl('http://myserver/sections/content/' + TID);
store.load( ... );
```

To abstract out this functionality away, it would be safer to add a method to your `Store` that creates the proper URL.

```
setUrlForTid: function(tid) {
    this.getProxy().setUrl('http://myserver/sections/content/' + tid);
}
```

Ideally, however, you wouldn't be using a global variable to manage this, and you likely won't have to after making this adjustment. You should be passing it around with the data you get from the list, similarly to how you're setting `TID` now in your `itemtap` handler.